# query to conditionally look up max value of a group

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a table, where I have names, group names and values. Each group name is always presented also as a single name. If a group name is presented as a single name, the group name field is always empty. A name can belong to a group, but is not required to. I give you the following example:

```
Name    Group    Value
-----------------------
name1 | group1 | 10,000
name2 | group1 | 12,000
name3 | group2 |  9,000
group1|        | 40,000
name4 | group2 | 30,000
name5 |        | 11,000
group2|        |  1,000
name6 | group1 | 19,000
```

I want to have the following result out of this table for each single name:

- if name belongs to group, take name, group name and max value of the group
- if name does not belong to a group, take name, name again as group name and value

Based on the example above, the result should look like below:

```
Name    Group    Max(V)
-----------------------
name1 | group1 | 40,000
name2 | group1 | 40,000
name3 | group2 | 30,000
group1| group1 | 40,000
name4 | group2 | 30,000
name5 | name5  | 11,000
group2| group2 | 30,000
name6 | group1 | 40,000
```

I know how to get it with two separate queries and some python data mingling. However I would like to know which is the most pythonic way to achieve it and if it is possible to get the same result with one single query?

Answer (score 0):

The most SQL-ic way is to use a single SQL query.

Computing two different values can be done with a [CASE expression](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#case) and a [correlated subquery](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#cosub):

```sql
SELECT Name,
       CASE WHEN GroupColumn IS NOT NULL
            THEN GroupColumn
            ELSE Name
       END AS "Group",
       (SELECT max(Value)
        FROM MyTable AS T2
        WHERE T2.GroupColumn = MyTable.GroupColumn
           OR T2.Name        = MyTable.GroupColumn
       ) AS "Max(V)"
FROM MyTable;
```

(But there is a [helper function](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#ifnull) to replace NULL values; the entire expression for `GroupColumn` can be simplified to `ifnull(GroupColumn, Name)`.)

Comment: thanks for this! I would think for the max(v) it would get the max value if GroupColumn is not null, and just the value if the GroupColumn is null. So for the row    `group2|        |  1,000 ` it would only result `group2| group2 |  1,000`, though the max value for group2 should be 30,000. What do you think?

Comment: I do think that I didn't think enough …

Answer (score 0):

```
.headers on
.mode column
.width 1 8 8 8

with
data as (
  select 1 n,'name1'  name, 'group1' groupcol, 10000 v union
  select 2 n,'name2'  name, 'group1' groupcol, 12000 v union
  select 3 n,'name3'  name, 'group2' groupcol,  9000 v union
  select 4 n,'group1' name, null     groupcol, 40000 v union
  select 5 n,'name4'  name, 'group2' groupcol, 30000 v union
  select 6 n,'name5'  name, null     groupcol, 11000 v union
  select 7 n,'group2' name, null     groupcol,  1000 v union
  select 8 n,'name6'  name, 'group1' groupcol, 19000 v
),
data2 as (select ifnull(groupcol,name) groupcol,* from data)
select
  n,
  name,
  groupcol,
  (select max(v) from data2 where groupcol=d.groupcol) maxv
from data2 d
order by n;
```

Result:

```
n  name      groupnum  maxv    
-  --------  --------  --------
1  name1     group1    40000   
2  name2     group1    40000   
3  name3     group2    30000   
4  group1    group1    40000   
5  name4     group2    30000   
6  name5     name5     11000   
7  group2    group2    30000   
8  name6     group1    40000
```

You need SQLite version 3.8.3 (2014) or newer for it to understand the WITH-clause. If you got an older version, the sql is easy to rewrite, just use parentheses with sub-selects behind FROM.